# during build my app i got error: MSBUILD : cordova-build error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'attrib' of null

Tags: android, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

I am new in mobile developing and i use VS 2015 for build simple app with apache cordova and ionic. I made app with two views: first - login page, second - page with list of items getting from remote server as json.

Everything is ok in Ripple emulator, but when i try to build real apk file i got this error:

```
MSBUILD : cordova-build error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'attrib' of null
TypeError Cannot read property 'attrib' of null
```

I spent many hours googling the same error but did not found any with this part: **property 'attrib'**.

How can i solve my issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Or how to get more detailed error?

Comment: It's a general null error, it's codes related, could you please post the html and js codes to show what you are trying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and discovered that this error rears its head if your AndroidManifest.xml has errors.  Once my manifest file is fixed, this error went away.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

just add this tag to config.xml :

```
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
 </author>
```